# Complex declaration in C- Programming language

Tags: c

I came across a very complex declaration which I could not understand:

```
char ( * ( * f[3]) ()) [5] ;
```

I want to know how to determine what is being declared.
Also, since this question was asked to me in an interview, I want to know whether these kind of codes are actually used in the software industry ?

If not, then what is purpose of asking ?

Comment: Type it into http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com ....

Comment: `f` is an array of 3 pointers to function, each returning pointer to an array of `5` chars.

Comment: It includes a deprecated non prototype-style function declaration.

Comment: These kind of complex statements are not used in real time coding.
The motive would have been to test your  knowledge specifically of operators and their precedence :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply break the declaration into parts.
The inner most pair of braces : ( * f[3] ) means 'f' is an array of 3 elements which are pointers.

`( *f )()` means 'f' is a pointer to function, so
`( * f[3] ) ()`  means f is an array of 3 pointers to function.

`( * ( * f[3] ) ())` means f is an array of 3 pointers to function returning a pointer.

Hence,

```
char ( * ( * f[3] ) ()) [5]  ;
```

means f is an array of 3 pointers to function returning a pointer to array of 5 characters